# Thymeleaf + webauthn client(browser)

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm looking into building an **spring-thymeleaf** application that supports passkeys based on **webauthn**.

https://github.com/webauthn4j/webauthn4j-spring-security/tree/master/samples shows the server using Java and the client using Angular. The server side is clear to me. What I'm wondering about is the client side and how to build the frontned with thymeleaf?
My sample idea:

```
<head>
    <!-- Include your JavaScript file -->
    <script th:src="@{/js/webauthn.js}"></script>
</head>
```

```
// webauthn.js
function initWebAuthn(challenge, userId, userName, displayName) {
    const createOptions = {
        publicKey: {
            // ... set up your create options using the variables
            challenge: Uint8Array.from(atob(challenge), c => c.charCodeAt(0)),
            user: {
                id: Uint8Array.from(atob(userId), c => c.charCodeAt(0)),
                name: userName,
                displayName: displayName
            },
            // ... other options
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('registerButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        navigator.credentials.create({ publicKey: createOptions.publicKey })
            .then((credential) => {
                // Process and send the credential to the server
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    });
}
```

Is this approach a valid alternative to using a webauthn client library? Or are there any plans to integrate webauthn with thymeleaf for more convenient implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have recently created a spring-thymeleaf application that supports webauthn.  That is exactly the approach I took.  The thymeleaf pages simply include javascript libraries which handle communication to browser supported Web Authentication API (WebAuthn).  On the server side I leveraged the Yubico FIDO libraries.  You are certainly on the right track.

Comment: how do you let thymeleaf pages include js lib? by `<script th:src="@{/js/webauthn.js}"></script>` ?

Comment: Yes that will work depending on your project structure, where you have your .js files resident.  From Spring boot documentation: "Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:

/META-INF/resources/
/resources/
/static/
/public/"